# Tradução de "wasteland"

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

Estou traduzindo uma modificação para um jogo e me deparei com o seguinte termo: **wasteland**.

No texto, "**wasteland**" é um bioma de vegetação escassa e que diminui consideravelmente a capacidade de sobrevivência do jogador enquanto ele estiver ali, dadas as circunstâncias extremas do bioma.

O termo em inglês denota, conforme o [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wasteland), uma região caracterizada por sua aridez ou destruição, geralmente inóspita.

Há alguma palavra em português que produza o mesmo sentido na língua-fonte?

Comment: Há também uma musica de mesmo nome 'Wasteland'- de uma banda inglesa chamada 'The Mission', que era conhecida na década de 80.

Answer (score 6):

Se o bioma é apenas inóspito (e não destruído), então **deserto** seria o termo simples que melhor corresponde à *wasteland*.

Mas, além do termo original ter vários significados (pode denotar desde uma região simplesmente não cultivada, até uma destruída, passando por uma desolada e/ou desértica), de qualquer forma a melhor tradução vai depender do estilo do jogo.

Pela descrição, **deserto** poderia ser apropriado mas, se for adequado à concepção artística do jogo, poderia ser mais interessante usar um bioma mais tipicamente brasileiro, como a **caatinga** ou o **cerrado**. No sentido mais amplo do termo, outras traduções possíveis são **sertão** e **selva**.

A depender do estilo da linguagem usada no jogo, uma palavra menos comum, como **páramo**, **ermo** ou **desolado**, poderia ser mais adequada ou, ao contrário, um termo meramente descritivo, como **região inóspita** ou **região desolada**.

Comment: Acho o último parágrafo particularmente bom como resposta. Já a parte do deserto, nem tanto - note-se que a palavra original usada não foi «desert», mas sim «wasteland».

Comment: @ANeves Sim, isto é claro, mas a questão original se refere ao *wasteland* como sendo um bioma caracterizado por um tipo de vegetação - e nenhuma das palavras do último parágrafo denota um bioma específico. *Desert*, além de um bioma, é um dos [sinônimos](https://www.freethesaurus.com/wasteland) de *wasteland* e, como uma [*barren or desolate area; forsaken place*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/desert), condiz bem com "deserto", [definido](https://dicionario.priberam.org/deserto) como "Lugar estéril e desabitado".

Comment: Omiti uma informação importante na descrição da pergunta: não há como traduzir "wasteland" para "deserto" porque o bioma "deserto" já existe no jogo.

Comment: @Diego Informação importante mesmo. Você pode contar mais sobre o jogo - estilo da linguagem, gráficos, etc.? `Desolado`, `região desolada` podem então ser uma boa opção, a menos que tenha que ter nome de bioma, daí tem que checar qual outras opções faz mais sentido no jogo.

Answer (score 2):

Os dicionários Inglês-Português oferecem como tradução para "wasteland" as seguintes opções:

- deserto
- terra inculta
- terreno baldio
- área devastada
- área desertificada
- etc.

Nenhuma dessas traduções me soa apropriada no contexto do jogo descrito pelo OP.  "Deserto" não corresponde exatamente à definição de "wasteland".  Nem o Sahara, o Atacama ou o Kalahari são chamados de "wasteland" pelos falantes da língua inglesa. "Terreno baldio" é geralmente um terreno pequeno em perímetro urbano, onde não há nenhuma construção e na maioria das vezes encontra-se coberto pelo mato. "Terra devastada" sugere uma região destruída por elementos da natureza, guerras, etc. "Terra inculta" não é um termo de uso corrente. Pelo menos, não pelas pessoas comuns que encontramos nas ruas. Por esse motivo, sugiro "semiárido" que, além de ser um adjetivo que define clima e vegetação, também é um substantivo.

Exemplos:

> - [**Situação Atual da Seca no Semiárido**](https://www.cemaden.gov.br/situacao-atual-da-seca-no-semiarido-e-impactos-janeiro-de-2017/)
> - [**Cultivo da palma no Semiárido**](https://www.embrapa.br/busca-de-publicacoes/-/publicacao/1046559/cultivo-da-palma-no-semiarido)

Sem fazer referência ao Semiárido Brasileiro, o uso da palavra "semiárido", isoladamente, pode se referir a qualquer região do mundo ([**ver mapa**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clima_semi%C3%A1rido#/media/File:K%C3%B6ppen_World_Map_BS.svg)), fria ou quente, onde tenhamos um terreno descampado com pouca chuva e pouca vegetação.

Relendo hoje a pergunta, acho que a palavra "inóspita", conforme sugerido por Stafusa em sua resposta, é o que soaria melhor como tradução para "wasteland" no contexto do jogo citado pelo OP.  Sugiro então **terra inóspita**, termo traduzido do latim "terra inhospitalis", e que já foi usado em mapas e narrativas antigas para descrever regiões desse tipo.

> "He discovered Cooper's Creek and reached as far as the Stony Desert, where his party was stopped by the aridity of the country and the blinding heat of midsummer in what he described as **Terra Inhospitalis**."
>   from [**A Documentary History of Australia: Colonial Australia, 1841-1874**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=l0JzAAAAMAAJ&q=%22terra+inhospitalis%22&dq=%22terra+inhospitalis%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi65rXj547gAhUvHbkGHd6gAmcQ6AEIMTAB)